# Disable App Transport Security while working with Socket.IO

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I am trying to connect to Socket.IO Server. I am using swift library

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Here is my sample code

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myIP:443];


    self.socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url opts:nil];

    [socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        NSLog(@"socket connected");
    }];

    [socket on:@"currentAmount" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
        double cur = [[data objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        [socket emitWithAck:@"canUpdate" withItems:@[@(cur)]](0, ^(NSArray* data) {
            [socket emit:@"update" withItems:@[@{@"amount": @(cur + 2.50)}]];
        });

        [ack with:@[@"Got your currentAmount, ", @"dude"]];
    }];

    [socket connect];
```

This is what i have used in my plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>xx.xx.xxx.xxx</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I am still getting

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

Then maybe it afterwards tries to connect to API with another address, that you have not provided in the `info.plist` file.
Just as a temporary thing, you could do this, to eliminated this Transport Security error:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```